# How to represent multiple images sizes in JSON-API response?

Tags: json-api

My app has users and each user has a photo, which can be downloaded in multiple sizes. How would you model this in JSON-API?

### Inline object

```
data: {
  photo: {
   small: "small.png",
   large: "large.png"
  }
}
```

The problem I see here is that when having say 6 image sizes and a list of 50 users, I'm sending 300 photo URLs over the wire, where most of them are not needed.

### Inline URL + param

```
data: {
  photo: "default.png"
}
```

This produces less data, but it's unclear how to get to the small/large version. This could be done by adding a request param: `?photo_size=small`, which would then returns a different photo url. Problem here: you have to know about the photo_size param. It's not clear from the response that it exists.

### Links

```
{
  links: {
    small_photo: "url to photo or url to user endpoint but with photo_size param (see above)"
  }
}
```

This feels `json-api`-like, but again would produce lots of json data. I'm also not sure what to link to (photo or user endpoint).

### URL templates

Instead of returning one URL per photo size, I could return a template and the available sizes, but afaik this is not part of/allowed(?) in JSON-API (yet?).

Answer (score 3):

If you are treating the images as attributes of the user then I don't think JSON-API is prescriptive about how links to external files are handled. Any of your techniques would be compliant with the spec.

Your first data structure would be the most straight-forward and given the image URLs would mostly consist of repeating sections they would compress very well, so the additional download size per image variation is likely to be negligible.

The following is pretty standard:

```
data: {
  type: "user",
  id: 1,
  attributes: {
    photos: {
      small: {
        url: "https://...",
        width: 50,
        height: 50
      },
      large: {
        url: "https://..."
...
```

Using a template seems like it would also be compliant as it's really up to the client to decide what to do with the data:

```
data: {
  type: "user",
  id: 1,
  attributes: {
    photos: {
      base: "https://...<size>.jpg",
      sizes: ["small", "medium", "large"]
...
```

Links don't seem appropriate, though they are very loosely defined by the spec, because the expectation is that they link to other API resources.

Inline is also not great for the reason you state, you don't want to presuppose that knowledge on the client.

You could also use the `fields` param to have the client request only particular photo sizes.